# Implement Android/iPhone App on a Website page

Tags: java, javascript, android, ios, mobile

Okay, so I'm currently looking to see if this is doable so I can hire a programmer. Can I implement let's say a messenger app that is on Android and iPhone just like kik messenger on a website, so the app would be available on the PC online too. If so what language(s) would complete this task? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not possible using native Android/iOS languages.**

These languages are designed to work on mobile devices, not on the web. This means you cannot just embed the source code of a mobile application into a web page.

You can however create a a web version of your application (depending on the complexity of the app). For example: you could create a web version of the mobile app using HTML, JavaScript and CSS. You could also (although slightly dated) create a Flash application and embed it in the browser.

Web apps are becoming more and more common with the rise of HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript. I recommend this book on building web apps: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-Web-Applications-HTML5-JavaScript/dp/1430240806

Comment: @Jon The question is about implementing an app on a website page. If (the same way you would with HTML5, CSS3 and JS) you were to rewrite a version of the application in Flash it's an option (although not one I would recommend)